# Manage admin account in magento

Tags: magento

I developed a site in Magento Professional edition few month back. After a long time I login in admin, magento through an error that admin password was expired. In how many days the admin account will expire and could we manage it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `System->Configuration`, `ADVANCED->Admin->Security` and see `Password Lifetime (days)` and `Password Change` fields.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE enterprise_admin_passwords
SET expires = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60)
```

Will give each admin another year.

Clear your cookies and try again.

Answer (score 0):

@SteveRobbins's query is good when it requires to re-activate all the admin users.

For re-activating just 1 admin user run this query:

`UPDATE enterprise_admin_passwords
SET expires = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60) WHERE user_id in (select user_id from admin_user where username='YOUR_ADMIN_USERNAME')`

Or just remove all the entries for that user in `enterprise_admin_passwords` table:

`delete from enterprise_admin_passwords where user_id in (select user_id from admin_user where username='YOUR_ADMIN_USERNAME');`